How can I send requests to a LOCAL(app) WordPress site via the REST API?
I have set up a LOCAL wordpress site, and I am trying to send HTTP requests via the REST API endpoints but I am constantly getting 401 Authorization errors. I tried the LOCAL Live Links & ngrok to create a live URL but to no avail. While I can access my posts via the REST endpoints on the browser, I cannot send any requests to it, although I am properly using basic Auth.
This was working before I migrated that site to a LOCAL environment. Does LOCAL actively refuse REST API requests?
